# ADC unresponsive when I use a slow starting power supply

Tags: stm32, embedded

I have a project using an STM32L412. It works fine on my bench power supply, but I made it to run on a piece of modular equipment which has a different power supply - this supply is slower starting. On this supply the board seems to work fine except the ADC freezes on power up - the PWM for the LEDs still works, the external interrupts still work, however the ADC is completely unresponsive. If I remove the reset capacitor, the circuit then works on the slower starting power supply and not on the faster starting one. Only the ADC is affected, the timers / PWM still work, the I2C is still transmitting to an external DAC.

I was advised to drop the debugger in after the board had frozen -  when I did this I could step through the whole program and anywhere I put a break point, it was reached. The registers are exactly the same using either power supply, with the exception that with the slow power supply, the ADC calibration register is 0 and the ADC always returns 0x800.

Sometimes the program freezes up when I *step into* the wait loop for the ADC conversion to complete, that's the only functional difference I could find

Does anybody know a reason why this might be happening? According to what I've managed to find online, as the behaviour changes depending on what capacitor I put on the reset, it appears it might be to do with the Programmable Voltage Detection / Brown Out Reset. As this is my first project I have no knowledge or experience of these things, or why they would affect only the ADC

any help much appreciated

Comment: power sequencing is a thing

Comment: A larger reset cap may help - or a long delay in your code before trying to initialize the peripherals. Possibly you're configuring something for a higher frequency than it's capable of running at with the lower operating voltage.